# How do I view Youtube comments?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I can't find anyway to view youtube comments. I can only see the description, the likes/dislikes, and related videos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [apparently not possible](http://www.nintendolife.com/news/2013/11/the_3ds_youtube_app_has_finally_gone_live) in the current version of the app. This may have something to do with Nintendo's policy of restricting unmonitored, user-generated content because of potential offensive material (which YouTube comments frequently qualify as).

Comment: Because Nintendo doesn't like "free chat". If they were to put in comments, they would be a post-only and come in a list of things to say like I like this, Or Good job!